# Email Headers with specific device and email client info?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, mime

Not sure if this is the correct site to post this but where within a MIME email message would expose the type of the device (mobile, tablet, etc,.) used to sent the mail as well as the email client itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this or requirement for the client to tell you what it is.

Some clients will add a header value (often X-Mailer, X meaning a header that wasn't part of the RFC's):

```
X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 16.4.3508.205
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1822)
X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (10B329)
```

Other clients may send nothing at all.

Another method of detection is to use external images referenced by the email and see what the client sends as a browser using the image server when the image is retrieved. This is relatively unreliable as most clients will disable remote images, but it can be used as an additional method to help you get slightly more accuracy.